# How to add Special Character Delimiter in spark data frame csv output and UTF-8-BOM encoding

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-csv

I have to write my spark data frame output into a csv file with  "|^| " Delimiter .
I am trying to do like this .

```
df.write.format("csv").option("delimiter", "\\|\\^\\|")
```

But getting below error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported special character for delimiter: \|\^\|

How to add UTF-8-BOM encoding the output file by default it is UTF-8?

In java if i add "\uFEFF" in the starting of the file the encoding of the file changes to UTF-8-BOM.Now how can i append this char in spark csv ?

Also if i go with below approach `df.rdd.map(x=>x.mkString("|^|")).saveAsTextFile("dir path to store")`

How would i partition my data based on column in data frame ?

Comment: I don't think spark-csv supports multi char delimiters

Comment: Why would you want to save using `|^|` character? spark-csv supports only one character. Why don't you use standard csv or just use only one character? and then when you read the file use that delimiter again. Can't you do like that?

Comment: Problem is that |^| delimiter is used by so many clients if change here every body else has to changes which is not feasible in my case .

Comment: @RameshMaharjan if i use this df.rdd.map(x=>x.mkString("|^|")).saveAsTextFile("dir path to store") then all option i am getting as csv will not be available by default

Comment: `then all option i am getting as csv will not be available by default` what do you mean?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan options like  partitionBy("DataPartiotion","StatementTypeCode") .option("header", "true")
  .option("codec", "gzip") and is there any chance that performance of the application will degrade ?

Comment: nope they won't degrade

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Any idea how to convert this as UTF-8-BOM format ?

Comment: nope i don't have any idea.

Answer (score 1):

just put

```
 df.write.format("csv").option("delimiter","^").csv("dir path to store")
```

and for MULTI char you can use below code

```
 df.rdd.map(x=>x.mkString("|^|")).saveAsTextFile("dir path to store")
```

Comment: And how do we partition in this solution

Comment: at the end, everything is RDD and so in this scenario performance will not impact

Comment: But what about partition in this case

Comment: There is  no impact on partition, number of partitions will remain same, if you need more details you can elaborate your question

Comment: I was saying if i go with saveAsText file option how would i apply below  options like partitionBy("DataPartiotion","StatementTypeCode") .option("header", "true") .option("codec", "gzip")

Comment: Hi i have updated my question can you please have a look

Comment: I have added separate question for better understanding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46599054/how-to-do-custom-partition-in-spark-data-frame-in-saveastextfile-option

Comment: There is one problem with this..Where ever `,` is found in the records i get `" "` in the final csv output ...I have created separate question for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47002414/adding-custom-delimiter-adds-double-quotes-in-the-final-spark-data-frame-csv-out/47003011?noredirect=1#comment80963283_47003011